# Zip an uploaded file not work

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I try to .rar an uploaded file which not work out well. The only things that is inside the .rar is folder \tmp\phpQWESDA etc etc. 
My code looks like:

```
function zipFile($fileName,$folder,$u) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($folder.'/'.$fileName.".rar", ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $zip->addFile($u);
    $zip->close();
    return true;
}

$tmpFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
zipFile($file,'uploads/'.$random.'',$tmpFile);
```

EDIT: (SOLVED)

Never mind, forgot to add #2 parameter at 
`$zip->addFile($u);`
 Should be 
`$zip->addFile($u,$fileName);`

Comment: You're trying to `.rar` it or `.zip` it? `zip` creates `.zip` files, therefore needs a `.zip` extension.

Comment: @I'L'l, as you can see in the code I trying to .rar it. `$zip->open($folder.'/'.$fileName.".rar", ZipArchive::CREATE);`

Comment: Wrong tool. You need something that `rars` files.

Comment: Changed it to Zip. Still gives me the file inside: `\tmp\phpQWESDA` etc

Comment: put a `.zip` extension on the end of it and see what it does.

Comment: Never mind, forgot to add #2 parameter att `$zip->addFile($u);` .. Should be `$zip->addFile($u,$fileName);`

Comment: Might as well post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to add #2 parameter at  `$zip->addFile($u);` Should be  `$zip->addFile($u,$fileName);`